# Request.files 400 Bad Request in flask

Tags: flask, upload

flask with a project in my project I'm uploading an application I'm developing. I have 2 image upload areas. I don't have any trouble when I load 2. 400 Bad Request: KeyError: I get an error in the 'gelinFoto' style when I upload an image or when I push the send button when I never load it. Where am I making a mistake?

```
def admin():
form = KisiForm(request.form)
    if request.method == "POST":
        gelinFoto = request.files['gelinFoto']
        damatFoto = request.files['damatFoto']

        if gelinFoto or damatFoto:
            yol = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + whuser
            yol = yol + '/profil'
            gfilename = secure_filename(gelinFoto.filename)
            dfilename = secure_filename(damatFoto.filename)
            gelinFoto.save(os.path.join(yol, gfilename))
            damatFoto.save(os.path.join(yol, dfilename))

        kisi = bilgi(gelinFoto = gfilename, damatFoto = dfilename)
        db.session.add(kisi)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("admin"))
    return render_template("admin/index.html",form=form)
```

Html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="col-12">
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Gelinin Fotoğrafı : </label>
  <div class="upload">
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='admin/images/upload.png') }}" class="uploadImage" alt="">{{ render_field(form.gelinFoto,id="gelinFoto",class="gdfoto",accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg") }} </div>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Gelinin fotoğrafını yükleyiniz.</small>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Damatın Fotoğrafı : </label>
     <div class="upload"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='admin/images/upload.png') }}" class="uploadImage" alt="">{{ render_field(form.damatFoto,id="damatFoto",class="gdfoto",accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg") }}
  </div>
  <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Damatın fotoğrafını yükleyiniz.</small>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view you have both

```
gelinFoto = request.files['gelinFoto']
damatFoto = request.files['damatFoto']
```

This is why you get that error

When the file is not provided, then there is no `request.files['gelinFoto']` for example, and Python tries to look it up, but it can't cause there is no key named `gelinFoto`!

The simplest trick is defining theme like this:

```
gelinFoto = request.files.get('gelinFoto', None)
damatFoto = request.files.get('damatFoto', None)
```

This way it uses an inline condition to get the keys, if they are not provided, then it sets the value `None`

Later in your code I see you did that again,

```
if gelinFoto or damatFoto:
    # ... Your other coders 
    gfilename = secure_filename(gelinFoto.filename)
    dfilename = secure_filename(damatFoto.filename)
    gelinFoto.save(os.path.join(yol, gfilename))
    damatFoto.save(os.path.join(yol, dfilename))
```

It's wrong, you are checking with it with `or` and then u except both to be not `None` !!

It's better to do the operation for each one separately, like:

```
if gelinFoto:
    yol = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + whuser
    yol = yol + '/profil'
    gfilename = secure_filename(gelinFoto.filename)
    gelinFoto.save(os.path.join(yol, gfilename)

if damatFoto:
    yol = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + whuser
    yol = yol + '/profil'
    dfilename = secure_filename(damatFoto.filename)
    damatFoto.save(os.path.join(yol, dfilename)

# I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this but about kisi line This is the best that came up to me ( ofcourse there are better ways )
if gelinFoto and damatFoto:
    kisi = bilgi(gelinFoto = gfilename, damatFoto = dfilename)
elif gelinFoto:
    kisi = bilgi(gelinFoto = gfilename)
elif damatFoto:
    kisi = bilgi(damatFoto = dfilename)
```

Comment: unfortunately, the problem has not changed. I get the same mistake.

Comment: @BeratBozkurt provide more information, like the whole Traceback message

Comment: @BeratBozkurt
Add this data as text/code to your question, by the way, u didn't changed what I said, How u expect the error to be gone?

Comment: @BeratBozkurt Sorry, it was a little mistake, updated the answer, `request.get` changed to `request.files.get`, this should work fine

Comment: one more mistake :) I get a local variable 'dfilename' referenced before assignment error in if dfilename and gfilename:

Comment: Gfilename = False and dfilename = False on top of if I solved the problem. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @BeratBozkurt Edited the answer again, You can vote up if it helped u and u can accept the answer if it's correct

Comment: ssave my day brow