# Flask KeyError: 'imageFile' in request.files - 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a Flask application that allows users to upload images and process them. However, I encountered a BadRequestKeyError when trying to access the uploaded file using request.files[].
Here's my Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/",methods=['GET'])
def start():
    return render_template("process.html")

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def end():
    imageFile = request.files['imageFile']

    image_path = "./images/" + imageFile.filename
    imageFile.save(image_path)

    return render_template("process.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Neural Network Visualization</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" />
     </head>
     <body>
      <h1 class="text-center">image classifier</h1>
      
      <form class="p-3 text-center" action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="img">
        <input class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit" value="predict image">
        <div class="cemter"> <h1>{{my_string}}</h1></div>
      </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

When I try to upload an image using the form in my HTML template, I get the following error
**werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'imageFile'
**

I have checked the name attribute of the file input field in the HTML form, and it is set to "imageFile". However, the error still persists. I have also made sure to use enctype="multipart/form-data" in the HTML form.

What could be causing this BadRequestKeyError and how can I resolve it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Show us the HTML, please.

Comment: I tried '''
imageFile = request.files.get('imageFile',None)
'''
[from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53240205/request-files-400-bad-request-in-flask?rq=1)

Comment: Does that look like HTML to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with flask `request.form` attribute to get the files

Comment: I tried ''' imageFile = request.files.get('imageFile',None) '''